# how to sort mapreduce results?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapreduce

I have written a method in C# which retrieves tweets from mongoDB and would like to count and sort authors by the number of retweets.

Right now, the method already performs map and reduce and returns unsorted results the following way:

```
public void RetweetsCount()
        {
            string wordMap = @"function wordMap() {

                            var usernameOrigin = this.text.match(/\brt\s*@(\w+)/i);

                            if (usernameOrigin === null) {
                                return;
                            }

                            // loop every word in the document
                            emit(usernameOrigin[1], { count : 1 });
                        }";

            string wordReduce = @"function wordReduce(key, values) {
                            var total = 0;
                            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                                total += values[i].count;
                            }
                            return { count : total };
                        }";

            var options = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
            options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Inline);




            var results = collection.MapReduce(wordMap, wordReduce, options);

            foreach (var result in results.GetResults())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToJson());
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know how sort results by descending count value (number of retweets)?

Comment: is results a List<> if so do results.Sort(); please tell what Type results is in your case..

Comment: results is MapReduceResult type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution. After retrieving results from MapReduce, I first converted the IEnumerable to list and then ordered the list the folliwing way:

```
            var results = collection.MapReduce(wordMap, wordReduce, options);
            IEnumerable<BsonDocument> resultList = results.GetResults();
            List<BsonDocument> orderedList = resultList.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x[1]).ToList();
```